# Show a subset is not path connected.

Tags: metric-spaces, path-connected

Show that the subset $\{(x, y) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid x\neq 0\}$ of $\mathbb R^2$ is not path-connected.

I know that $X$ is path connected if any two points in $X$ are connected by a path in $X$, but unsure how to show this for this question. Could it been done by contradiction?

Comment: Yes. Assume that there is a path from left to right and consider its $x$-coordinate. What does the intermediate value theorem tell you?

Comment: This set, lets call it $X$, is $\mathbb R^2$ without the $y$-axis. So pick a point $(x_0,y_0)$ on any side of the axis and draw a circle of radius smaller than $|x_0|$. The interior of that circle is an open ball around $(x_0,y_0)$ completely contained in $X$. Therefore, each side is an open set, and together they give $X$. Hence $X$ is not just not path-connected, but not connected at all.

Answer (score 0):

The space $A:=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2:x\not=0\}$ is not connected as $U:=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2:x>0\}$ and $V:=\{(x,y) \in \Bbb R^2:x<0\}$ are two disjoint non-empty subset of $A$ with $A=U\sqcup V$. Hence $A$ is also not pathwise-connected.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ the set in question. Then $(-1,0), (1,0) \in A.$ Let $c=(c_1,c_2): [0,1] \to \mathbb R^2$ be a continuous path with $c(0)=(-1,0)$ and $c(1)=(1,0).$

Then: $c_1(0)=-1$ and $c_1(1)=1.$ Thus there is $\xi \in (0,1)$ such that $c_1(\xi)=0.$ But then we have that $c( \xi) \notin A.$

Comment: Typo  - $c_(0)$.